# 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

Tags: python

I keep getting this error while trying to run this code from Kaggle. After researching it seems its a version thing. I am running this on Collab and I tried on Jupyter notebook as well. I also tried to write a get_feature_name function , but no luck.

Help.

[image: Error]
[The Kaggle Code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/andls555/heart-disease-prediction/notebook)

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names_out)? Perhaps you need `get_feature_names_out()`?

Comment: @G.Anderson yes i Tried this function as well.. doesn't work  same error